# How to add a wildcard in a regexp repeated character class

Tags: regex, grep, wildcard

I'm trying to see if there is a way in an RE to express a match for a word consisting of a selection of given letters plus one wildcard letter.

For example, find all words in the system dictionary containing any mix of C, O, I, and any one other letter, in any order, without reusing a letter already matched, and using up all provided letters. So in this case, an RE would need to match

```
coif
coil
coin
coir
foci
icon
loci
rico
```

and maybe others that I am missing.

I'm not sufficient of a mathematical logician to know if this is even possible in a regexp.
It doesn't have to be done entirely in a regexp — if it uses several stages that's fine; it can be postprocessed in a script. I can't find a representation like `'^[oci.]*$'` (wrong) that even begins to address this.

Comment: I am not sure if c, o, i, will come together or not. If it does then this might work?

((c|o|i){1}(c|o|i){1}(c|o|i){1})

Comment: ([^cio])(?=.*c)(?=.o)(?=.*i).+  Try this one out. If you limit this to 4 letters it should work.

Comment: chaining a few lookaheads could work. F.e. `^(?=.*[i])(?=.*[c])(?=.*[o])(?!.*(\w).*\1)[a-z]{4}$`

Comment: @stackFan in this example all the letters (c,o,i) must occur once each in any order

Comment: arundeep LukStorms Those return no matches

Comment: @PeterFlynn It does expect that the multiline flag is used, for lines with 4 letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said `It doesn't have to be done entirely in a regexp`, this will work using any POSIX awk:

```
awk '/^.{4}$/ && /c/ && /o/ && /i/ && /[^coi]/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all. Solved with a loop so it's extensible

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). What makes you think [the answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64618562/1745001) is less extensible than whatever loop you came up with?

Comment: I need to parameterise it to deal with any string, not just the sample letters I posted.

Comment: That would be trivial but that's a different question from the one you asked and I answered. Post a new question if you can't figure out how to do that after attempting it yourself.